# Is an E-ticket required to check-in?

Tags: tickets

Is having an E-ticket mandatory to confirm my flight reservation?

Comment: What do you mean by "an E-ticket"? A printout of the confirmation e-mail? An E-ticket is just a single number, referring to an entry in a database.

Answer (score 2):

With e-tickets, the ticket itself is a record in an airline database.

In my experience at manned check-in desks you just hand over your passport and the airline finds your e-ticket and checks you in.

On the other hand at unmanned kiosks the system generally does ask you for ticket details to confirm who you are. Presumably because the automated kiosks are less able to check the security features of a passport than a manual check-in.

Comment: Several Airlines (including AA) have let me check in with just my passport (it reads the MRZ) and the destination airport.

Answer (score -1):

Nobody ever wants to see or know your ticket number, e-ticket or paper ticket.

You need to have bought a ticket, obviously, or you can't fly, so you implicitly have to have a ticket number. But you only ever need it when you want to retroactively add the miles to your frequent flyer account.

Comment: Airline websites often ask for it when you want to change your booking or when you're checking in online.

Comment: I have been flying with at least thirty different airlines in the last two years, and nobody ever asked for it - all you need is your booking code. Do you have an example?

Comment: Yea that's what I meant too, booking code or e-ticket number. But you'll need one or the other, your name and identification documents alone don't suffice.

Comment: On multiple occasions when flying on Lufthansa when Air Canada sold me the ticket (eg YYZ-MUC-Berlin and then home again), at the airport I have had to provide Lufthansa with the long e ticket number fished out of my emails. I don't know why, but I know that I have had to do it.

Comment: I've needed the ticket number to claim frequent flyer miles that didn't post automatically, but that's a bit of a special case.